# How to redirect the controller to the same page and my form div with another div?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, controller

These are the two divs :

1.The form:

```
 <div class="span4" id="subscriptionForm">
                <div class="p30">
                    <h4>Newsletter</h4>
                    <form class="soundest-subscribe-form" style="width: 100%;"
                          action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/validate" method="post">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="soundest-subscribe-input"
                               placeholder="Enter your email address" required/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe!" class="soundest-subscribe-submit"/>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

2.The success message which I want to appear after the submission of the form until then it has to stay hidden:

```
<div id="success" style="display: none;">
                <p class="text-success">You successfully subscribed !</p>
            </div>
```

This is the controller method which handles the validation of the form :

```
@RequestMapping("/validate")
    public String validate(Subscriber subscriber) {
        EmailValidator emailValidator = new EmailValidator();
        if (emailValidator.validate(subscriber.getEmail()) && !foundInDatabase(subscriber)) {
            if (service.create(subscriber)) {
                System.out.println("Added succesfully");
            } else {
                System.err.println("Unsuccesfull creatin subbscriber");
            }
        } else {
            System.err.println("Invalid");
        }
        return "index";
    }
```

In case everything is fine I want to redirect the user to the same page where he subscribed and show the success message instead of the form. How to do that ?

Comment: redirect to another page and show the message there. any issue with that?

Comment: It is better to use two different views. Because, in your case, when users will press refresh in browser after successful subscription, form will be shown again.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much sir !